# Not receiving Stripe Microdeposit verification emails in Test mode

Tags: stripe-payments

I am currently working on to integrate Stripe payments with our existing application, using the Stripe's custom web elements. But while testing different payment methods as described in [this link](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#non-card-payments), I am not receiving the Microdeposit verification email from Stripe for ACH Bank direct payment method. I do receive the acknowledgement email from Stripe that I have accepted the terms & conditions (mandate), but the email with the verification link is not received. Is there any process that we need to follow to receive the Microdeposit verification emails from Stripe?

Comment: This isn't really a development question, but based off https://stripe.com/docs/payments/ach-debit/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=checkout#send-transaction-emails-in-test-mode - have you activated your Stripe account as the docs mentioned? If you have done so already, you would probably want to check in with Stripe Support who would be able to better advise n what's the criteria required to receive those emails

Comment: Thanks for the response @alex, Yes the account is active and as I said, I am getting the email from Stripe regarding accepting the mandate, but not receiving any email with the micro-deposit verification link. I posted this question here to get the quick help if someone already have faced this issue and might know the solution which is not mentioned on the Stripe's documentation.